# Let A and B be Boolean algebras and f : A → B is an isomorphism,and A is atomic.

Tags: representation-theory, boolean-algebra

Let A and B be Boolean algebras and f: A → B is an isomorphism, and A is atomic.

(a) B is atomic, (b) B is complete (c) A is atomless (d) B is atomless

I think the answer is (A) by the representation theorem

edit:

also, I found similar questions online

---

Let A and B be Boolean algebras and f : A → B is an isomorphism,
and A is complete.

(a) B is atomic, (b) B is complete (c) A is atomless (d) B is atomless

---

Let A and B be Boolean algebras and f : A → B is an isomorphism,
and A complete and atomic

(a) B is complete and atomic, (b) B is finite (c) A is atomless (B) is
atomless

Comment: why do you think that? isomorphisms preserve the BA structure, so the image of an atom is an atom etc. Can more answers be correct?

Comment: no it's only one answer

Comment: What is the statement of  the representation theorem you're using ?

Comment: "If B is a finite Boolean algebra, then B is isomorphic to the power set
P(S) of some nonempty finite set S. This is Stone’s representation theorem for
finite Boolean algebras." from this resource [https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/55337078.pdf]

Comment: sorry I wrote it wrong I think the answer is (a) not (b) since it's isomorphic so we can see the same structure in BA "B"  as "A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $A$ because isomorphisms preserve the BA structure, so images of atoms are atoms etc. Not because of a representation theorem.

Comment: does it also preserve the completeness of BA?

Comment: @D0mBas3 Of course. If $B' \subseteq B$ then take the join of $f^{-1}[B']$ in $A$ and its image is the join of $B'$ etc. So $B$ has all joins etc.

Comment: @D0mBas3 All these questions follow the same boring pattern.

Comment: thank you so much, can you recommend a good reference for boolean algebras and atoms 

I am preparing for an exam and I am using the above reference with "Schaum's outline of theory and problems of boolean algebra"

But I think I miss some important concepts.

Comment: Halmos' book on Boolean algebra is good (but maybe too hard for you?) It explains all of this.

Comment: Yeah, I was using it but It wasn't easy for me, but thank you so much for helping.

Comment: You might find Davey and Priestley's Introduction to Lattices and Orders easier than Halmos.